# How to iterate through every property in an every Object in my list of Objects vb

Tags: vb.net

So I have a list of Objects and I want to get every property in every object and save it as a string.

Object looks like

```
Public Class parameters
    Public Property test As String
    Public Property test_type As String
    Public Property user_test_name As String
    Public Property meas As String
    Public Property spec_min As String
    Public Property spec_max As String
    Public Property spec_unit As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return user_test_name
    End Function
End Class
```

This is what i have so far

```
For Each parameters In param
    Dim myType As Type = GetType(parameters)
    Dim properties As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo() = myType.GetProperties()

    For Each p As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In properties
        MsgBox(p.Name)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: … so where exactly is your problem? The code should more or less work.

Comment: except it doesn't! It keeps going throuhg the first object over and over!

Comment: No it doesn’t do that – But all your types are identical so the output will of course be identical.

Comment: Ohh Nvm, I wanted the values in each property. I think i worded the question wrong